# countermodel interpretation - another example with existential quantifiers

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-explanation, predicate-logic

Still struggling with interpretation in logic. I have this:

∀xp(x) ↔ ∀xq(x), ∀xq(x) ↔ ∀xr(x) |=∃x(p(x) ↔ r(x))

1.
I first tried to solve it with a resolution method, and got stuck on this:

$ \lnot px \lor qx, px \lor \lnot qx $ from the first premise

$ rx \lor \lnot qx, qx \lor \lnot rx $ from the second

$ \lnot px \lor \lnot rx, px \lor rx $ from the negated conclusion

I could not find any atomic sentence to "eliminate" and don't know how to proceed.

2.
I tried a "human interpretation", to search for values that would evaluate the premises as True and the conclusion as False.

I read it as:

- for all value x of P, and for all values x of Q they are equivalent when their values are the same (first premise)
- for all value x of Q, and for all values x of R they are equivalent when their values are the same (second premise)
- there exist one value that makes P equal to R

And I thought the above is true, since if P is equivalent to Q and Q to R, there must be some P equivalent to R.

But it is wrong because the solution shows a countermodel:
Universe = {a,b}
p:  { b}
r:  { a }
q:  { }

As a test, I tried to change the conclusion to ∀x(p(x) ↔ r(x)) (and the countermodel is p:  { 1 }
r:  { 0 }
q:  { 1 }

and to :

∃xp(x) ↔ ∃xr(x)
and the countermodel changes to:
p:  { }
r:  { 0 }
q:  { }

while I was expecting at least being equal to ∃x( p(x) ↔ r(x) ).

- Can you show how to solve this step by step ?
- Can you help understand why the counter model changes in the examples above ?

Comment: hi @ryang, I upvoted your answer that is certainly correct, but still working out  concepts that are not obvious for me, probably linked to the evaluation of the models: e.g. the passages "For all three countermodels, ,, are not universally true, so the two premises are satisfied." and the evaluation of the values "the given countermodel indeed fails to satisfy that." I let the question open if others want to clarify those steps.

Answer (score 1):

> > $$∀xp(x) ↔ ∀xq(x),\:\: ∀xq(x) ↔ ∀xr(x) \:\models\: ∃x(p(x) ↔ r(x))$$
>
> I read it as:
>
> - for all value x of P, and for all values x of Q they are equivalent when their values are the same (first premise)

Try formalising your above translation. Do you see that the only sensible way to do so is: $$∀x \,\big(Px ↔ Qx\big)\,?$$ Instead, the first premise actually says:

- P and Q are both universally true or both not universally true.

Note that not being universally true is not logically equivalent to being universally false: $$¬∀x\,Px \quad\not\equiv\quad ∀x\,¬Px.$$

> the solution shows a countermodel:
> $$\text{Universe}= \{a,b\}\\ p: \{ b\}\\ r: \{ a \}\\ q: \{ \}$$

> I tried to change the conclusion to $∀x(p(x) ↔ r(x)),$ and the countermodel is $$p: \{ 1 \}\\r: \{ 0 \}\\q: \{ 1 \}$$

> and to $∃xp(x) ↔ ∃xr(x),$ and the countermodel changes to $$p: \{ \}\\r: \{ 0 \}\\q: \{ \}$$
> while I was expecting at least being equal to $∃x( p(x) ↔ r(x) ).$
>
> Can you help understand why the counter model changes in the examples above ?

For all three countermodels, $P,Q,R$ are not universally true, so the two premises are satisfied.

1. The original conclusion wants some value that gives $P$ and $R$ the same truth value; the given countermodel indeed fails to satisfy that.
2. The second conclusion wants $P$ and $R$ to be universally equivalent; the given countermodel indeed fails to satisfy that.
3. The third conclusion wants $P$ and $R$ to each to be true for some value (not necessarily a shared value!) or each be universally false; the given countermodel indeed fails to satisfy that.

The following rewrites are helpful; here they clarify that the two copies of $x$ aren't necessarily the same object:
$$∀x \,Px ↔ ∀x \,Qx \quad\equiv\quad ∀x \,Px ↔ ∀y \,Qy\\
∃x \,Px ↔ ∃x \,Qx \quad\equiv\quad ∃x \,Px ↔ ∃y \,Qy$$